# Downloading files from iframe'd website in Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: android, html, cordova, iframe

I'm looking for a way to download and save files into device storage, using Phonegap/Cordova.

To be more precise:

I've created an app, and it contains an iframe with MP3s archive inside. This is an example website that's included in the iframe:

http://www.paranormalium.pl/index.php?akcja=archiwum

Clicking on any of the "Pobierz" buttons should start downloading a file, however, in my Phonegap/Cordova app nothing happens.

I've tried some 'file transfer' plugins, however, they all seem to rely solely on what is in app and not in iframe.

Is there any way to 'force' my Phonegap/Cordova application to download files from external website and then store them in device's storage?

Comment: did you find any solution? can you share if you do so.

Answer (score 0):

Thats works:

```
function DownloadFile(urlFile)
{
   location.href=urlFile;
}
```

Comment: where do we need to add this function?